# sysadmin denied on sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-agent-job

I'm trying to run a SQL Server Agent Job manually but keep getting an error that basically says the domain account is denied on sp_send_dbmail.

The job has multiple steps that run stored procedures. The domain account is sysadmin and it's also the owner of the job. Each step in the job runs as the sysadmin account and my account is also a sysadmin.

It should run under (I assume) sysadmin security context, but I'm lost why it keeps failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure answer but a way to see what's going on :

On the machine that sends mail , please run :

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami'
```

then see who is the user which tries to send mail and grant permission to that user.

Also ,go to the `services.msc` to your instance , right click  , properties and go to `logon as` and see if that user has permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the sp you recommended is disabled. The SQL Server Agent is running under Local System.

Comment: 1) So enable it :-) . 2) I didn't talk about sql server agent but the instance service. http://i.imgur.com/Iv0A4aH.png

Comment: I'd like to try that but I'm not authorized unfortunately. The sql server instance is also running under local system.